# Should I use app.get or app.all in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a little webapp using express.js and I wondered if if it is best to use `app.get()` or `app.all()` as handler for a specific page.

For example:

```
app.get('/', getHomePage)
app.get('/about', getAboutPage)
app.use(notFoundPage)
```

instead of

```
app.all('/', getHomePage)
app.all('/about', getAboutPage)
app.use(notFoundPage)
```

Now I realize that in the first example anyone who sends another http request than a `get` request will be presented with the error page, however since I am only interested in `get` requests I think it would be fine too send the error page to the other requests or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to be as specific as possible: if you're only interested in `GET` requests, use `app.get()`.

A 404 *Not Found* will (/should) be generated for other methods (like `POST`).

Comment: This is definitely the way you should go.

Comment: Ideally he should be using express router instead of app. http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router

Answer (score 0):

If your application have authentication, definitely you have to go for app.all("*",callback) to check whether your all request is authorized or not for both app.get() and app.post()